# Packer ssh_private_key_file is invalid: Failed to read key c:/xxxxx: no key found

Tags: packer

I use Packer form Hashicorp to create VMs.
Faced such a problem:

```
packer build jessie64_hv.json
virtualbox-iso output will be in this color.
1 error(s) occurred:
 ssh_private_key_file is invalid: Failed to read key 'C:/users/xxxx/test_key.ppk': no key found
```

Part of the json file:

```
  "type": "virtualbox-iso",
  "guest_os_type": "Debian_64",
  "guest_additions_mode": "disable",
  "headless": "{{user `HEADLESS`}}",
  "disk_size": "{{user `DISK_SIZE`}}",
  "http_directory": "http",
  "iso_url": "{{user `ISO_URL`}}",
  "iso_checksum": "{{user `ISO_CHECKSUM`}}",
  "iso_checksum_type": "{{user `ISO_CHECKSUM_TYPE`}}",
  "ssh_port": 22,
  "ssh_private_key_file": "C:/users/xxxxx/test_key.ppk",
  "ssh_username": "root",
  "ssh_wait_timeout": "10000s",
  "shutdown_command": "echo 'vagrant' | sudo -S /sbin/shutdown -hP now",
  "vm_name": "{{user `VM_NAME`}}",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ppk` keys, they are specific to Putty. Packer can only read standard OpenSSH keys.

To convert your key do something like

```
puttygen privatekey.ppk -O private-openssh -o privatekey.pem
```

And then use the `privatekey.pem` in packer.

For more info see: [Converting a ppk to pem](http://www.ramsmusings.com/2014/02/20/converting-a-putty-ppk-file-to-a-pem-file-for-accessing-aws-ec2-instances/)

Comment: Thank you.. but now such an error: Error waiting for SSH: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none password publickey], no supported methods remain

Comment: And where do you add your public key?

Comment: If you are just getting started with Packer and don't have a 5 feet long unix-beard I strongly recommend that you don't start from scratch but instead build on what others have done and adapt that to your use case. A good start repo for VirtualBox Vagrant boxes is https://github.com/chef/bento

Comment: It is added via the preseed file: d-i preseed/late_command string \
    in-target mkdir -m 700 -p /root/.ssh; \
    in-target /bin/sh -c "echo '---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY -------- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----' >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"; \
    in-target chown -R root:root /root/.ssh; \
    in-target chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys; \

Comment: A public key in `authorized_keys` should look something like: `ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nza[.. alot more here ...] john.doe@example.com`

Comment: thanks for the help. The error was in the key, after the rewrite earned